# Exact sequences and direct sum of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have $3$ $A$-modules $M$, $N$ and $P$ such that there exist 2 exact sequences

$$0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow P \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$$
$$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow P \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$$

Does this means that $P$ isomorphic to $M \oplus N$? If not what is the counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $P=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ (the base ring is $\mathbb{Z}$, the integers).

Comment: and what for $M$ and $N$ ?

Comment: @brick $M=N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ah ok. I got it. Thanks!